# Efficiently find the group with largest effect on standard deviation

Tags: standard-deviation, algorithms

I have some "groups" of measurements with varying numbers of items, for example:

```
 Group 1: { 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.1 }
 Group 2: { 2 }
 Group 3: { 2.1, 1.2 }
 etc ...
```

(Any single item within a group I'll refer to as a `measurement`).
I'd like to find the group with the largest adverse effect on the standard deviation of all the measurements.  My current approach is the following:

1. Find the standard deviation of all measurements
2. Remove a single *group*
3. Find standard deviation with all measurements except those in the removed group
4. Return the removed group
5. Repeat steps 2 through 4 for each group
6. Report the removal that caused largest reduction to the standard deviation

This approach works for what I'm doing, but it's very computationally expensive.

I'd like to know if there is a more efficient way of calculating which group will have the largest adverse effect.  My first guess is maybe a weighted average would work, but I don't have a ton of faith in my guess.

EDIT:
Second, more educated guess (based on the actual formula for standard deviation): For each group: Sum of (measurement - mean_of_all)^2

Comment: Here's what I would do: 1. Find the mean of all measurements. 2. Compute the standard deviation of each group separately with respect to that overall mean found in 1. 3. Rank each group by the result of 2. Wouldn't that work? This would be much cheaper computationally than what you're doing, because you're never computing the standard deviation of "almost the whole data set".

Comment: @AdrianKeister Yes, that would certainly be less expensive.  I, guess whether it works or not is if it's mathematically correct.  See my edit, I think it's along the same lines, but doesn't do as much of the calculation of the standard deviation (your step 2)

Comment: Your edit is actually precisely what I had in mind, with a few differences in formula. The standard deviation you should calculate as 
$$S_g=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(y_{g_i}-\overline{y})^2},$$
where $S_g$ is the subgroup's standard deviation, and $y_{g_i}$ ranges over the subgroup, and $\overline{y}$ is the mean over all the data points in all subgroups.

Comment: You can argue that this is correct, by virtue of the fact that variances for independent variables that are added together add. That is, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $\text{Var}(X+Y)=\text{Var}(X)+\text{Var}(Y).$

Comment: @AdrianKeister Thanks.  Do you want to write up an answer?

Comment: Your formula is actually the correct one.

Comment: I wasn't entirely sure, thanks for confirming.  Now to code it up!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let your overall sample be $y_1, y_2,\dots,y_n,$ and let
$$\overline{y}=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^ny_i$$
be the overall sample mean. Partition the sample into $m$ subgroups, which we will denote by $y_{g_i}.$ Now the variance for the entire sample is given by
$$\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\overline{y})^2.$$
We can also write this as
$$\frac{1}{n-1}\!\left[\sum_{j=1}^m\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n_j}(y_{g_i}-\overline{y})^2\right)\right]$$
To find which subgroup contributes the most to this variance, simply form the sums
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n_i}(y_{g_j}-\overline{y})^2$$
for each subgroup and rank the subgroups by the results.